# Conflicting libraries in iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-plot

So basically I have two libraries that are I think conflicting with each other. I have the following settings for the key **"Library Search path"**:

`"$(SRCROOT)/projectname/Release-iphone/lib"` for one of my libraries, and `"$(SRCROOT)/projectname"` for another.

I have added a `CorePlot` library into my project but to work it requires the following **Linker Flags**: `-ObjC -all_load`.

Now when I add one or both of them I get the following message and my project won't build:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMHTTPFetcher in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname-chibchblpntaapfagqcohtkixhib/Build/Intermediates/projectname.build/Debug-iphoneos/projectname.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTMHTTPFetcher.o
    /Users/user/Dropbox/Projectname/projectname/projectname/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMHTTPFetcher in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname-chibchblpntaapfagqcohtkixhib/Build/Intermediates/projectname.build/Debug-iphoneos/projectname.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GTMHTTPFetcher.o
    /Users/user/Dropbox/Projectname/projectname/projectname/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
ld: 176 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The problem turns out to be with the Google API library `libGTLTouchStaticLib.a` but I don't get how do linker flags influence it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you have the source file included directly into your project as well as having a link to the library.  You should choose one or the other (probably the library).

Comment: The thing is I didn't reference those particular files to be imported from anywhere - I just dragged and dropped them to my project.

Comment: I'm just going by the location names that it's reporting.  The .../DerivedData/... one is normal for a compiled source file and the libGTLTouchStaticLib.a is a library reference.

Comment: Yep, that one is added directly to the project by copying into it, it shouldn't be?

Comment: It turns out the library `libGTLTouchStaticLib.a` was compiling its own files that were already included in my project.

Answer (score 0):

screw -all_load that was a hack to load categories. should work without it

Comment: Doesn't! Doesn't work without either `-all_load` **or** `-ObjC`

Comment: ObjC is needed -- all_load is bad in any case... can you post what errors you get?